.NET 8 api.video SDK compatibility
maybe it's a dumb question, but with the quantity of .NET Frameworks and .NET Core's I get confused.
So I'm trying to use the SDK from this website https://api.video/ and I have targeted my project to .net 8
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <StartupObject>Streaming.MainStream</StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ApiVideo" Version="1.3.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="JsonSubTypes" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="105.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

But the SDK doesn't work when I try to import the libraries and the package throws this warning
Package 'ApiVideo 1.3.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework ,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the target project framework 'net8.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

On the website they say
Frameworks supported
.NET 4.0 or later
So I'm missing something, it's this the old .NET I don't know.

The "Frameworks" tab of the nuget.org page will tell you what runtimes the package targets and is compatible with https://www.nuget.org/packages/ApiVideo#supportedframeworks-body-tab

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69901972/1043380
